# Windows 10 won't sleep, even after overriding drivers

Tags: windows-10, sleep

This is pretty much a fresh Windows 10 installation.

I rebooted, logged in and opened CMD as an admin:

```
C:\Windows>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] High Definition Audio Device (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0887&SUBSYS_10438444&REV_1003\4&c43e6d5&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] USB Audio Device (USB\VID_0556&PID_0001&MI_00\8&3925350b&0&0000)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
An active remote client has recently sent requests to this machine.
[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller
```

I executed the following:

```
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "High Definition Audio Device" SYSTEM
powercfg -REQUESTSOVERRIDE DRIVER "USB Audio Device" SYSTEM
```

I rebooted, but am still getting the same results with powercfg.  Should I still be seeing these?  The machine sleeps, sporadically.  I always get the same results with powercfg.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation recently.  What started it, as I discoverd, was because I had plugged a cable to the "Line In" on the back panel, and then turned on "Listen to this device" in the audio settings.  Computer wouldn't sleep at all, powercfg showed the same "audio stream in use" message.  Turning off "listen to this device" fixed it.

My phone has a better audio DAC than my M5A97 R2.0 mobo, so I was playing music from my phone, through the PC.  I guess I'll settle for playing music right from the PC for now.